# Show that $\mathbb{Q} \cap B(x,r) \neq \varnothing$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $x$ be an irrational number and let $r>0$. Consider the open ball $B(x,r) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\mathbb{Q} \cap B(x,r) \neq \varnothing$.

---

*My thoughts:* I was thinking that maybe you could engineer a sequence that consists of rational numbers which converges to $x$ - perhaps something along the lines of n times the integer part of x divided by n:

$$\bigg\{ \frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n}\bigg\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$$

But how do I show formally that this in fact converges to x - I'm not that familiar with working with integer parts and limits. If I can show that I can just pick a number in the sequence so I have rational number closer to x (say $\epsilon$ close) than $r$ and I'd be done.
Or maybe I am way off or there is an easier way of showing it, any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You don't need a sequence. You just need a single rational number in this ball. And you can produce rational numbers close to irrational ones by truncating their decimal expansion.

Comment: If x is rational then you are done, if it is irrational then you can find an rational number arbitrarily close to it because Q is dense in any interval (including an open neighbourhood)

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that every real number has a decimal representation? If so, just pick an appropriate initial segment of the decimal representation of the center of the open ball/interval (or of any number in the ball/interval, for that matter).

Comment: Hans Engler and Dave L. Renfro: 
I don't think I'm meant to use decimal representation to show it.

Malcolm:
I'm actually suppose to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ so I can't use this fact

Comment: How do you define $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You can also show that there is a subset of rational numbers (a doubly infinite sequence) such that any two successive members are separated by less than $r$. Then there must be at least one member in that open ball.

Comment: Hans Engler: How do I construct such a sequence of rational numbers?

Comment: The sequence $\dots, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, \dots$ has entries are separated by 1. Can you turn this into a sequence with entries separated by $\frac{1}{2}$? or by $\frac{1}{10000000}$? I guess what you need to show that is that there is a natural number $m$ such that $\frac{1}{m} < r$. That's one of the axioms of the real numbers.

Comment: Can I determine m say without assuming r has k zero decimals before the first non-zero decimal and pick $m=10^k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\tag 1 \text{For any } s \in \Bbb R, \; \lfloor s \rfloor \le s$$

$$\tag 2 \text{For any } s \in \Bbb R, \; s \lt \lfloor s \rfloor + 1$$

Let the irrational (or not) number $x$ and integer integer $n \gt 0$ be given.

Using $\text{(1)}$, we can write

$\tag 3  \frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n} \le x$

Using $\text{(2)}$ and employing algebra, we can write

$\tag 4  \frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n} \gt x -\frac{1}{n}$

Combining $\text{(3)}$ and $\text{(4)}$,

$$\tag 5  x -\frac{1}{n} \lt \frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n} \le x $$

Using the [squeeze theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/542307/432081), the sequence $\bigg\{ \frac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}{n}\bigg\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Within the reals, B(x,r) = (x-r, x+r).
So the problem becomes finding a rational in (a,b) for all a < b.
That can be done by use of the Archimedean property of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In the real set, $B(x,r) = (x-r, x+r)$. So the problem becomes: prove that in $(a,b)$ for all $a < b$ there is a ractional numbers.
Let's suppose $0\leq a$.
To do that we will use that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n\in \mathbb{N}$, this could be simply prove thinking at the $\lim_{n\to +\infty} \epsilon\cdot n=+\infty$ for a fixed $\epsilon$.
So now we know that exist $n$ such that $n\cdot (b-a)>1$ so $\frac{1}{n}<b-a$.
Now let's consider the set $$A=({m\in\mathbb{N}:\frac{m}{n}\leq a})$$ it is 
limited above, infact $n\cdot$ a is bigger then any element of A, so admit sup. $L=supA$ and by the definiction of sup we have that for any $1>\epsilon>0$ exist $u\in A$ such that $L-\epsilon \leq u \leq L$ so $u\leq L \leq u+\epsilon \leq u+1$, so we have that $u$ is a element of $A$ and $u+1$ not, in fact is bigger that L. $$\frac{u}{n}\leq a \leq \frac{u+1}{n}=\frac{u}{n}+\frac{1}{n}<a+(b-a)=b$$
So the rational number $y=\frac{u+1}{n}$ satisfies the thesis. 
If $a<0<B$ the number $0$ satisfies the thesis.

If $b\leq0$ we have already test the existence of $y$ such that $-b<y<-a$ so $-y$ satisfies the thesis.